# php xml into as3

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I can't find out how to get some data from a PHP file across into Flash AS3. I can get a simple string across, however my data is XML data pulled from a database. I need the xml to be brought into AS3 and then I can forceDownload from within flash.

This is my php line which grabs the two columns of data.

```
list($data, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($queryDownload);
```

The $data is the XML code and $name is the name of the file.

How do I send that to AS3 in a way that keeps the data as XML data? and get AS3 to use that to create a downloadable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [AS3 documentation for XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html).

```
var xml:XML;

var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://yourdomain.com/file.php");
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function urlLoader_complete(evt:Event):void { 

    xml = new XML(evt.target.data);    
}
```

In the above snippet the PHP file is named **file.php** & is located at **yourdomain.com**

Your PHP code simply needs : `echo $data`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would it be then possible to use that XML to create a download such as:

fileReference.download();

Comment: why not? parse through the nodes of the xml, get the file path & use fileReference.download(<file path>)

Answer (score 0):

You should send the XML object serialized as string and then create an XML object on the client using new XML(xmlString), where xmlString is the server response.